# BASH How to improve performance of JSON parsing with jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, performance, jq

Context: I have a scenario where I need to perform copies of backups from one system to another. I want the backups list to be configurable, so I went with a JSON approach inside the script itself.

The list contains key (name of the backup to show in output), user to ssh with, and path to get the backup from.

Example:

```sh
backups_to_perform='[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "user": "user1",
    "path": "path1"
  },
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "user": "user2",
    "path": "path2"
  },
  {
    "key": "key3",
    "user": "user3",
    "path": "path3"
  },
]'
```

The reason I'm going with JSON, is that I wanted to have a similar structure to a python dictionary, since associative arrays can only have `key:pair`, instead of `key{key:pair; key:pair}` (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

This is how I'm parsing the JSON:

```sh
  while read -r backup; do
    IFS=, read -r key user path <<<"$(jq -cr '"\(.key),\(.user),\(.path)"' <<<"$backup")"
    rsync_backup "$key" "$user" "$path"
  done < <(jq -cr '.[]' <<<"$backups_to_perform")
```

rsync_backup is just a function to perform rsync that accepts those args.

It possible there's a better solution to achieve the backup copies that what I want, but I'd like to improve this type of code so I can better apply it next time.

My problem is that this seems to take some time when the JSON is big (I've cut back to 3 for this post). It also looks like my way of parsing the JSON is very convoluted but I couldn't make it work any other way.

It's probably bad that I'm calling `jq` once to feed the loop, and then call it again for each iteration.

Comment: I would use csv file and GNU Parallel `parallel --csv` No jq and faster due to parallel execution. I'm sure you can convert csv to python dict too.

Comment: I would switch to a language that has a JSON parser, rather than using `jq` to try to produce a simpler input format that `bash` can handle.

Comment: @chepner If it's only about providing an output that you can parse with bash then jq is enough no?

Comment: "Dictionary" is just what some languages call their associative arrays. In JSON, they are called "objects".

Comment: @Fravadona Only assuming you know enough about the values stored in the object to know if constructing a CSV or TSV value is safe. The problem is there are no proper data structures for passing values from `jq` to `bash`, only strings. Using a language that doesn't need to rely on such string encodings to pass values from one *function* to another is simpler.

Comment: Even though `jq` can safely construct valid CSV or TSV itself (e.g., `jq -n '["foo,bar", "baz"] | @csv'`), `bash` doesn't provide facilities for parsing that result.

Comment: @chepner, you can unescape jq's TSV with bash `printf -v var %b`; the only problem lays in missing fields, which could probably be handled directly in jq (I'm searching how to  do it)

Comment: @lojza I would like to use a "native tools" only approach, as this script can move to other systems and I would like to not be dependent on other tools that I have to install. But thank you, I did end up looking into it.

Comment: @chepner, the reason this is in bash, is because I'm refactoring an old script, and most people that will use it or might change it are more comfortable with bash. I also like to stick to bash when basically all I'm doing is done with native linux commands, like `rsync`.

Comment: @ikegami, correct. What I meant to say is that in python, it's easier to just use 'associative arrays of associative arrays' which are called dictionaries in python, but that don't exist in bash, hence going with a JSON approach.

Comment: But you *aren't* just dealing with external commands. You are trying to process data in order to find arguments for that command. Most people who are "comfortable with `bash`" probably don't know anything more about how it works than is needed to run the script, so you may as well write the script in an appropriate language.

Comment: @chepner I understand, you're probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

A few things to consider:

- You can avoid using `jq` inside the `while` loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r key user path
do
#   rsync_backup "$key" "$user" "$path"
    echo "key=$key user=$user path=$path"
done < <(
    jq -cr '.[] | "\(.key),\(.user),\(.path)"' <<< "$backups_to_perform"
)
```

- You should safeguard against typos in the JSON that will lead to `null` values (for example if you typed `"usr":` instead of `"user":`).
- You should allow the use of commas in `"key":` and `"user":`, and of any character (but the `NULL BYTE`) in `"path":`.

---

With all that in mind, I would choose the TSV format as `jq` output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# safety check
if $(jq 'any(.[]; .key and .user and .path | not)' <<< "$backups_to_perform")
then
    jq -c '.[] |select(.key and .user and .path |not)' <<< "$backups_to_perform" |
    awk -v prefix="[WARNING] missing attribute in record: " '{print prefix $0}'
fi

# doing the backups
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key user path
do
    # unescape TSV values
    printf -v key  %b "$key"
    printf -v user %b "$user"
    printf -v path %b "$path"
#   rsync_backup "$key" "$user" "$path"
    echo "key=$key user=$user path=$path"
done < <(
    jq -r '.[] | select(.key and .user and .path) | [.key,.user,.path] | @tsv' <<< "$backups_to_perform"
)
```

You can test it with this input:

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' backups_to_perform <<'EOJ'
[
  {
    "__comment__": "comma in key value",
    "key": "key,1",
    "user": "user1",
    "path": "path1"
  },
  {
    "__comment__": "newline in key value",
    "key": "key\n2",
    "user": "user2",
    "path": "path2"
  },
  {
    "__comment__": "mispelled user attribute",
    "key": "key3",
    "usr": "user3",
    "path": "path3"
  },
  {
    "__comment__": "path containing ascii range [0x01-0x7f]",
    "key": "key4",
    "user": "user4",
    "path": "\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\u007f"
  }
]
EOJ
```

Comment: This was really insightful. Specially the first part about simplifying the loop. It looks obvious now but I didn't have the capacity to improve it. I don't think there will be commas inside key user or path, but the TSV approach looks cleaner, easier to read for others, while making it more robust. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Can you please explain the reasoning behind the `select(.key and .user and .path)`? I tried your previous version of the answer, where it was just `<(jq -r '.[] | [.key,.user,.path]|@tsv ' <<<"$backups_to_perform")` and it worked fine.

Comment: @pr3c0g The previous version tested the `path` variable for determining if there was an empty field (and print a warning for it). Now the JSON objects that contain null attributes are directly discarded with this jq's `select`; if you exit the script during the `# safety check` then you won't need it